# Optical weight selection with fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I'm using LuaTeX version 0.76 and fontspec version 2.3c.
I have the full family of MinionPro, but fontspec seems not to choose the appropriate optical weight.
While it works for the roman font of Latin Modern, it even seems not to work with e.g. small capitals (but then, I don't know for sure if this is available with Latin Modern).
The SizeFeatures feature of fontspec seems not to work either. MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}%

%\setmainfont[%
%%SizeFeatures = {%
%%{Size =     -8.41, OpticalSize = 8},%
%%{Size = 8.41-13.1, OpticalSize = 11},%
%%{Size = 13.1-20.0, OpticalSize = 19},%
%%{Size = 20.0-,     OpticalSize = 72,  Font = Minion Pro Disp}},% -- Doesn't work either
%Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},%
%Ligatures={Common, TeX, Contextual},%
%SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}%
%]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textsc{Optical weight}\\
\scalebox{0.44}{\Huge\textsc{Optical weight}}
\end{document}
```

Is there a workaround to get the correct optical weights? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
More information:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/54efhdo6nl56lcv/ltx-fontspec-optical-size-3.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: 1) Small caps for Latin Modern come as separate font, not a feature, and just like with CM they are only available at the default 10pt size. 2) *fontspec seems not to choose the appropriate optical weight* -- well, which weight does it choose for what size? The optical sizes of Minion Pro aren’t available as a free font, so the testing needs to be done by somebody who owns it. Can you run the script [posted here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.lualatex.devel/1208/focus=1219) and paste the output somewhere?

Comment: Also, here’s a more complete test file: https://bitbucket.org/phg/lua-la-tex-tests/src/tip/ltx-fontspec-optical-size-3.tex Run it with ``\setmainfont{Minion Pro}``, the output is valuable for debugging.

Comment: @phg I added the output of the more complete test file. It seems that there is no Minion Pro Disp included, even though it should (and it definitely is installed)

Comment: @Barrabas Thanks, the question is much clearer now! Please update the Luaotfload package to version 2.4 (only a couple days old). This issue should be fixed by now.